# Groovy to Java Code

Tags: java, groovy

I know that such "general" questions shouldn't be asked, but can someone help me translate the following code from Groovy to Java. My main problem is, that I really do not know which datatypes in Java are similar to the ones of Groovy. Any help is welcome!

Many thanks!

```
  def registrations = [:]

  public void register(Class clazz, MessageListener listener) {
      def listeners = registrations.get(clazz)
      if (!listeners) {
          listeners = [] as Set;
          registrations.put(clazz, listeners)
       }
       listeners << listener
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be something like this (untested):

```
Map<Class, Set<MessageListener>> registrations = new HashMap<Class, Set<MessageListener>>();

public void register(Class clazz, MessageListener listener) {
    Set<MessageListener> listeners = registrations.get(clazz);
    if (listeners == null) {
        listeners = new HashSet<MessageListener>();
        registrations.put(clazz, listeners);
     }
     listeners.add(listener);
 }
```

Comment: Well, I posted mine 4 seconds before you, so I win! ;D

Edit: Or maybe not, since mine does not compile because of lacking semi-colons.

Edit2: But I fixed that, too.

Comment: *shamefully deletes his post*

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to the question ([@Stmated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8258117/6509) has that covered), but if this is for a comparison to compare Groovy and Java, I believe your Groovy code could be better:

```
def registrations = [:].withDefault { [] as Set }

public void register(Class clazz, MessageListener listener) {
  registrations[ clazz ] << listener
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001066/converting-java-code-into-groovy)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `java.util.HashMap` and `java.util.HashSet` for `registrations` and `listeners` respectively.